# Transferring money to a PayPal account from Western Union

Tags: money-transfer, paypal

PayPal, or at least under my PayPal account, allows me do perform direct deposits into the said account.

Basically they issued me a PayPal account number and a Wells Fargo custodial account.

Is it possible then to transfer money to this account without raising red flags?

It's just that I'm overseas and there are no banks that can do international transfers or which PayPal supports.

I know I can send to my other bank account from WU then transfer to my PayPal account, but I just wanted to research first. Maybe it's possible and maybe it's not.

Comment: Obligatory anti-scam check: Does the "they" in "_Basically they issued me_" refer to someone who contacted you online about a "job offer" or some such, or a "friend" who've you've only met online? If anything like that, proceed with extreme caution. Especially when you add Western Union to the mix.

Comment: @TripeHound. No, the reason I specifically used that phrase was because it may not be the case for every PayPal account holder, considering how PayPal does extensive ID scrutiny to make sure you are who you are and doing legit business with them. If there's not requirements then every PayPal account holder should have a Wells Fargo custodial account. Check this out https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/Custodial-account/td-p/1446880

Comment: The they is referring to PayPal, just to clarify